# JWPlayer autostart and repeat dynamic playlist

Tags: javascript, php, jwplayer

I'm working with JWPlayer on an application to generate playlist dynamically with PHP
Here's my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
    playerInstance.setup({
        playlist: [
        <?php                       
        foreach ($playlist_details as $key => $video_array) {
            if ($last_array_item == $video_array['id']) {
                ?>
                {
                  file: '../../uploads/videos/<?php echo $video_array['video_file'];?>',
                    image: "",
                    width: "100%",
                    aspectratio: "16:9",
                    title: '<?php echo addslashes($video_array['video_title']);?>',
                    description: '<?php echo addslashes($video_array['video_description']);?>',
                    mediaid: '<?php echo $video_array['id'];?>'
                }
                <?php
            }
            else {
                ?>
                {
                  file: '../../uploads/videos/<?php echo $video_array['video_file'];?>',
                    image: "",
                    width: "100%",
                    aspectratio: "16:9",
                    title: '<?php echo addslashes($video_array['video_title']);?>',
                    description: '<?php echo addslashes($video_array['video_description']);?>',
                    mediaid: '<?php echo $video_array['id'];?>'
                },
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>

        ]
    });
</script>
```

which works fine, BUT... I'm unable to make the playlist start playback automatic on page load from the 1st video. I tried with 'autostart: true' but it doesn't seem to work.... I'd like also the playlist to shuffle (start over from the 1st video when reaches the last one).
Is there an option for that?
Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved here: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/16228742-start-a-playlist-automatically

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
repeat:'always',
```